# Getting list of tables with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have been using the [Schema.getTables()](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Schema.html#getTables--) method in jOOQ to get the list of tables in my schema, but today I found out that method is returning the list of tables that existed when we executed jOOQ's code-generation, not the tables that exist at this point in time.

My specific use case is we create tables over time (automatic partitions) and our Java service does some operation on them.

Is there a way in jOOQ to get the current list of tables from the DB?

I could resort to querying `information_schema.tables` directly, but I'd prefer to reuse a method from jOOQ if one is available.

Answer (score 3):

You can access your runtime meta information via jOOQ's [`DSLContext.meta()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta()) API, which is a jOOQ wrapper over JDBC's [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

Comment: I tried `using(configuration).meta(MY_SCHEMA).getTables()` with the same result: it returns even the dropped tables that existed when I ran jOOQ's code generator. I used the debugger and I see it ends up calling the same `getTables0()` method as before, which has a fixed list of tables. I tried `meta()` with no arguments, but then I hit: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8520